# Tensorflow-tf.concat() shows different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
t1 = [
    [[0],[1],[2]],
    [[3],[4],[5]],
]
print(sess.run(tf.shape(t1)))
print(sess.run(tf.concat(t1,1)))
print("**********")
t2 = np.arange(6).reshape([2,3,1])
print(sess.run(tf.shape(t2)))
print(sess.run(tf.concat(t2,1)))
```

then it shows

```
[2 3 1]
[[0 3] [1 4] [2 5]]
[2 3 1]
[[[0] [1] [2]] [[3] [4] [5]]]
```

t1 and t2 have the same shape and value, why the result is different?

Answer (score 0):

Because `t1` is a `list`, and `t2` is not.

`tf.concat` concatenates a list of tensor. So `t1` is seen as a list of 2 tensors of size `3x1` to concatenate. On the other hand, `t2` is a numpy array that is converted to a single `2x3x1` `Tensor`, and there is nothing else to concatenate this tensor with.

I think what may have surprised you is that `t1` is interpreted differently depending on the context. `tf.shape` expects a `Tensor` as an argument, not a list of tensor, so when passed to this function, `t1` is interpreted as a `2x3x1` tensor.

Comment: When I read the code `self.lstm_outputs, self.final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, self.lstm_inputs, initial_state=self.initial_state)
 seq_output = tf.concat(self.lstm_outputs, 1)`. According to what you mean,it seems useless. Because `self.lstm` is a single `Tensor` instead  of a list of tensors.But why the programmer did this?

Comment: It is not always a `Tensor` -- [it actually depends on `cell.output_size`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn).

Answer (score 0):

From documentation page on [tf.concat()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat):

```
tf.concat(
values,
axis,
name='concat')
...
Concatenates !!the list!! of tensors values along dimension axis,
...
the data from the input tensors is joined along the axis dimension.
```

`tf.concat()` takes **a list** of tensors as an input.
t1 is a list. `tf.shape(t1)` converts it into a single tensor and returns its shape. `tf.concat(t1,1)` sees t1 as a list 2 objects: `[[0],[1],[2]]` and `[[3],[4],[5]]`. It converts t1 into a list containing 2 tensors of shape (3,1), concatenates them and returns tensor of shape (3,2).
To verify this, you can run the following example:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  t1 = [
    [[0],[1],[2]],
    [[3],[4],[5]],
  ]

  t100 = [[0],[1],[2]]
  t101 = [[3],[4],[5]]
  print(sess.run(tf.concat(t1,1)))
  # construct a list from t100 and t101
  print(sess.run(tf.concat([t100, t101],1)))
```

Both will return the same result.
On the other hand, t2 is a numpy array, tf.concat(t2,1), sees t2 as a list containing a single numpy array, therefore no concatenation takes place and it essentially returns you t2.

Comment: When I read the code `self.lstm_outputs, self.final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, self.lstm_inputs, initial_state=self.initial_state)
 seq_output = tf.concat(self.lstm_outputs, 1)`. According to what you mean,it seems useless. Because `self.lstm` is a single `Tensor` instead  of a list of tensors.But why the programmer did this?

Comment: @jicocaer the rnn cell in tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, ...) may take nested tuple of Tensors as an input, thus dynamic_rnn may produce the nested tuple of outputs, therefore tf.concat() might be necessary. Obviously I cannot tell why the programmer did what he did unless I see the full code. As the other user mentioned, the documentation on [tf.nn.dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) provides more details on output shapes.